# Visualize motion/gesture from acceleration data

Tags: c++, opengl, data-visualization, gesture

I have implemented a gesture detection algorithm where a user can define his own gestures. The gestures are defined by acceleration values send from an accelerometer.

Now my question is: **Is it possible to visualize the performed gesture, so that the user can identify what gesture he performed?**

My first idea and try was just to use Verlet Velocity Integration (as describec here: http://lolengine.net/blog/2011/12/14/understanding-motion-in-games) to calculate the corresponding positions and use those to form a line strip in OpenGL. The rendering works, but the result is not at all what the performed gesture looked like.

This is my code:

```
    float deltaTime = 0.01;
    PosData null;
    null.x = 0.0f;
    null.y = 0.0f;
    null.z = 0.0f;
    this->vertices.push_back(null);
    float velX = 0.0f;
    float velY = 0.0f;
    float velZ = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < accData.size(); i++) {
        float oldVelX = velX;
        float oldVelY = velY;
        float oldVelZ = velZ;
        velX = velX + accData[i].x * deltaTime;
        velY = velY + accData[i].y * deltaTime;
        velZ = velZ + accData[i].z * deltaTime;
        PosData newPos;
        newPos.x = vertices[i].x + (oldVelX + velX) * 0.5 * deltaTime;
        newPos.y = vertices[i].y + (oldVelY + velY) * 0.5 * deltaTime;
        newPos.z = vertices[i].z + (oldVelZ + velZ) * 0.5 * deltaTime;
        this->vertices.push_back(newPos);
    }
```

I am using a `deltaTime` of 0.01 because my accelerometer sends the acceleration data every 10 milliseconds.
Now i am wondering: Is there something wrong with my calculation? Could it even work this way? Is there a library which can do this? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

as the theoretical physics and monte-carlo-simulation man, I've thought about the discrepancies you've observed. You wrote that the "real" gesture curve (3D) didn't resemble at all the calculatet curve. You might want to consider several aspects of the problem at hand. First, what do we know about the "real" gesture curve in space. We certainly do have "some" curve in mind, but that needn't look much like the "real" curve performed by one's hand. Second, what do we know about the quality of the accelerometer, about its accuracy, about its latency or other intricacies? Third point, what do we know about the "measured" acceleration data, do they fit "some" nice and smooth curve when drawn in x-y-plot shape? If that curve isn't really very smooth-looking, then one needs assumptions about the acceleration data to perform a linear, or better, a spline-fit. Afterwards you can integrate simply by analytical formulae. -- You might think in terms of signing electronically when the UPS parcel service asks you to, what does your signature look like on that pad? This is what probably happens with your acceleration system, without some "intelligent" curvature-smoothing algorithm. Hope my comment could be helpful in one way or another ... Regards, M.